# How to install Musescore 3 on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, compiling

I'm using Debian testing and I'm having problem with installing Musescore 3. I'm trying to compile it, and I have tried following these guides:

[General linux and BSD instructions](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/developers-handbook/compilation/compile-instructions-linux-bsd-git)

[Ubuntu 14.10 and 16.04 instructions](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/developers-handbook/compilation/compile-instructions-ubuntu-1410-and-1604lts-git)

It seems like the issue is that there's one package that I'm missing, because the guides asks me to install `qtquick1-5-dev` but that package is no longer available in Debian. I know that Musescore exists as a package, but it is to old. Also, I don't want to use the app image.

The error message begins like this. Tell me if you need more.

```
In file included from /home/me/src/MuseScore/mscore/musescore.cpp:116:
/home/me/src/MuseScore/mscore/startcenter.h:24:75: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 class MyWebUrlRequestInterceptor : public QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor {
                                                                           ^
```

Comment: The header containing `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` class was not included before. The most likely reason is some incompatibility between your sources and the Qt version.

Comment: I changed the question to better suit my ultimate goal, and since there are no answers that get's invalidated by this, it seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like a compatiblity issue for now.

meanwhile, gnome-software gives flatpak support in debian testing.
so you  can try the flatpak : https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.musescore.MuseScore

or

appimage : https://musescore.org/en/download/musescore-x86_64.AppImage

Comment: Never heard about Flatpak before, but it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Flatpaks & Appimages should be discouraged, because they can include malware & spyware. I really don't know why Musescore developpers are using this package format...

Comment: Please don't spread FUD. Why would a file provided directly by the MuseScore team contain malware or spyware? Why would that be any different in case they distribute RPM or DEB files?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem on Lubuntu 18.04. I solved it by installing Qt from its own installer (downloadable from https://www.qt.io/download). I chose to install Qt5.8, but it also works for Qt5.12 (which occupies thrice as much space on disk). You need to

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/<username>/Qt/5.8/gcc_64
export PATH=/home/<username>/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/bin:$PATH
```

assuming that's where you installed Qt, if not change accordingly. Follow installation instructions otherwise. You might want to add those exports to your .bashrc if you expect to continue using Qt.